# Importing a module that ends with .js in react/javascript

Tags: javascript

Any idea how I can import a module who's name ends with .js?

example of module https://www.npmjs.com/package/bandchain2.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Client } from '@bandprotocol/bandchain.js';

export default App = () =>{
    return(
    <div></div>
    );
}
```

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@bandprotocol/bandchain.js' in '/mnt/g/Projects/test-app/src/components'
```

Comment: try to remove the .js: `'@bandprotocol/bandchain`

Comment: doesn't compile still. problem is the library's name is literally '@bandprotocol/bandchain.js'

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the package correctly? Use `npm list --depth=0` to verify.

Comment: please share your package.json

Comment: yup

```
/mnt/g/Projects/test-app$ npm list --depth=0
paint@0.1.0 /mnt/g/Projects/test-app
├── @babel/core@7.5.5
├── @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.12.1
├── @bandprotocol/bandchain.js@1.4.0
├── @brainhubeu/react-carousel@2.0.4
├── @emotion/core@10.1.1
├── @emotion/styled@10.0.27
├── @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.36
```

truncated

Comment: it's in package.json if you guys are asking and i install it by doing npm install @bandprotocol/bandchain.js

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem with no compile issues and imported it as:

```
import { Client } from "bandchain2.js";
```

You're importing it as **bandchain.js** when the npmjs you provided is bandchain2.js

Comment: still getting the same compilation issue, is there any setting you're using in your environment? The issue i'm facing is react thinks it's a js file in my components folder instead of using the module in my node_modules folder

Comment: I edited my answer - your import should be `@bandprotocol/bandchain2.js` and not `@bandprotocol/bandchain.js`

Either you have an older version which should be updated or the npmjs you provided is not correct.

try running `npm update`

Answer (score 0):

`import { Client } from "@bandprotocol/bandchain.js";`

and you should add the following line to your package.json file.
`"browser": { "crypto": false }`

discussion of the relevant topic:https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using node v16.
Seems that the problem only occurs with node 14 or the react/create-react-app version installed